# prevent insert data to database if specific atribute already exist

Tags: php, mysql

I want to prevent duplicate values into a database table from a form using PHP.

I have a table **data** on database that have atribute dataid(auto increment as primary key), data1, data2.

And I have a simple form like this

```
<h2>Enter your data</h2>
<form action="script.php" method="post">
    Data 1:<input type="text" name="data1" /></p>
    Data 2:<textarea name="data2"></textarea></p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add Data" />
</form>
```

It's **script.php** for inserting data to database

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        //connect to the database
        $conn = mysql_connect('host', 'username', 'password', 'dbname') or die(mysql_error());

        //insert results from the form input
        $query = "INSERT INTO data(data1, data2) VALUES('$_POST[data1]', '$_POST[data2]')";

        $result = mysql_query($conn, $query) or die(mysql_error());
    }
?>
```

but it will insert any data from the form to database.
How can I **prevent insert data to database if data1 already exist**?

Comment: You can make columns `unique` in your DB

Comment: If he makes it unique and tries to run the query as written, it will error out. Now, maybe that's fine, but the better way to handle it would be to not only make the column unique, but check for data1's existence in the table, and if it's not there, run the insert query.

Comment: Or you could do what Naruto suggested and also use a not deprecated mysql api and wrap your insert in a try/catch block. That way you don't need to do two queries.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comments. can you give me the code how to do that?

Comment: @P.Gearman if it errors out, you just catch the error and handle it... like mike said

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not use the [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It’s so awful and dangerous that it was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices. Your user parameters are **not** [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) and there are [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) that can be exploited.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. In this short example you have a number of dangerous [SQL injection vulnerabilities](http://bobby-tables.com/) coming from a complete lack of [proper escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php). Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication) built-in.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to your problem is to make the column unique so the database takes care of enforcing this constraint.  You can do this by creating a unique index or constraint:

```
alter table data add constraint unq_data_data1 unique (data1);
```

You can then use this in an `insert` to ignore duplicates by using `on duplicate key update`:

```
INSERT INTO data(data1, data2)
    VALUES('$_POST[data1]', '$_POST[data2]')
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE data1 = VALUES(data1);
```

The `ON DUPLICATE KEY` part doesn't really do anything.  It is a no-op.

Also, you should parameterize your queries, so you are not subject to SQL injection and so the query plans can be cached.  But that is another matter.

Answer (score 0):

make column data1 unique

```
ALTER TABLE `data` ADD UNIQUE (`data1`);
```

change your query like this to ignore insert when data exist

```
$query = "INSERT IGNORE INTO data(data1, data2) VALUES('$_POST[data1]', '$_POST[data2]')";
```